# Disable CPU scaling with U 1404

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, cpu, cpu-frequency

I know there are a lot of things about this topic but I couldn't find anything not older than 4 years. As the stuff develops so fast I hope it is fine to ask again a few years later.

What is currently a good way to disable the CPU throttling on Ubuntu and Debian systems?

A few old ways I found (are they still recommended, is it done differently today):
https://askubuntu.com/questions/3924/disable-ondemand-cpu-scaling-daemon
http://jahanzebnotes.blogspot.de/2013/02/turn-off-cpu-throttling-ubuntu.html
https://superuser.com/questions/179329/disable-frequency-scaling-ondemand-daemon-on-ubuntu-10-04
https://endless-turtles.com/2012/06/disabling-cpu-frequency-scaling-in-ubuntu/